# How can you ASG tags for an EC2 instance in the ASG using EC2MetaData and AWS java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using the AWS Java sdk and EC2MetaData, how can you get the ASG tags for an EC2 instance belonging to the ASG?

Comment: Tags are not available via EC2 Instance Metadata. You would need to get `DescribeInstances()` to obtain instance and tag information. You can probably filter it to only return instances that belong to an Auto Scaling Group -- Auto Scaling adds tags to the instance to identify which Auto Scaling group 'owns' the instance.

Comment: You can now access tags via EC2 Instance Metadata if you enable the option for it.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#allow-access-to-tags-in-IMDS and https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/instance-tags-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata-service/